# failure to load glyphs in Ubuntu 15.04 (RStudio)

Tags: ubuntu-15.04, rstudio

Whenever I run RStudio in Ubuntu, I get strange output in Terminal "load glyph failed err=6..."
The following is taken from my Terminal where I open RStudio.

```
ypitcan@PitcanStat:~$ rstudio

load glyph failed err=6 face=0x2de33f0, glyph=2797
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x2de33f0, glyph=2797
```

Then when I close the RStudio application I also get the message

```
QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it so these errors don't come up again?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but I also receive these "error" messages but they seem utterly innocuous. I always run rstudio from Terminal and it has always worked fine.

I wouldn't sweat over this.